# Large Analytics Database Responsive Retrieval (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, reporting, analytics, data-retrieval

I want to create a 'google analytics' type application for the web - i.e. a web-based tool to do some reporting and graphing for my database. The problem is that the database is HUGE, so I can't do the queries in real time because they will take too long and the tool will be unresponsive.

How can I use a cron job to help me? What is the best way to be able to make my graphs responsive? I think I will need to denomalize some of my database tables, but how do I make these queries faster? What intermediate values can I store in another database table to make it quicker?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "HUGE".  How many records are we talking about?  I've been surprised how well databases perform on vast numbers of records, with proper optimization, and how much the people of SO can help with this.

Comment: Hundreds of millions of millions of records per table ~ 300 million, needing to join 5 to 6 of these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business Intelligence (BI) is a pretty mature discipline - and you'll find answers to your questions in any book on scaling databases for reporting & data warehousing.

A high-level list of tactics would include:

- partitioning (because indexes are little help for most reporting)
- summary tables (generated usually through a batch process submit via cron)
- you need a good optimizer (some databases like mysql don't - so make poor joining decisions)
- query parallelism (some databases will provide linear speedups just by splitting your query into multiple threads)
- star-schema - a good data model is *crucial* to good performance

In general dynamic reporting beats the pants off static reporting - so if you're after powerful reporting I'd just try to copy data into an appropriate model, use aggregates, possibly change the database to get a good optimizer and the appropriate features rather than run reports in batch.